# Does the finitistic dimension conjecture hold for cellular algebras?

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, homological-algebra

I want to study some non-trivial examples which could make the finitistic dimension conjecture holds. Also I want to find all the simples modules of these examples. So I want to know whether the finitistic dimension conjecture hold for cellular algebras. Or just for some specific kinds of cellular algebras.

The definition of cellular algebras can be found in
https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF01232365.pdf

Appreciating for every help and idea.